# How can you weight data for splitting in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I want to split my data into a development and validation set. Data should be split by ID. For around 30% of my <strike>data</strike> individuals I have rich observations, with the remaining 70% having sparse data.

For my development set, I want to include all of the individuals with rich data (even if it might not be good practice to do so), and then fill up with individuals with sparse data. The validation set should not contain any rich data.

Some example data:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID     CONC  TIME  RICH
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      55.0     1     1
2 A      52.6     2     1
3 A      50.2     3     1
4 A      47.9     4     1
5 E      40.7     2     0
6 E      38.3     2     0
```

I am aware of the `sample()` function, but I am at a loss at how to "randomly" split data with weights.

EDIT: All IDs have several observations, and so the randomization should be on the ID depending on RICH. An individual is assigned as having rich data if there are more than *n* observations.

EDIT 2: The 75%/25% split should be on IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one raw approach :

```
#Unique ID's
n <- unique(df$ID) 
#Get all rich ID's
rich_set <- unique(df$ID[df$RICH == 1])
#count number of unique ID's in development set
development_n <- ceiling(length(n) * 0.75)
#select random Id's to complete development set
devel_ID <- sample(setdiff(n, rich_set), development_n - length(rich_set))

#Subset data
development_set <- subset(df, ID %in% c(rich_set, devel_ID))
validaton_set <- subset(df, !ID %in% c(rich_set, devel_ID)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I realized that I added non-representative example data. The randomization should be based on ID, and weighted by RICH, as all individuals have several observations. My apologies.

Comment: @mhh I am not clear about your expected output. Do you want to select all the rows from ID with rich data ? So something like `df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() > n)` ?

Comment: That is correct, all rows associated with an ID should be included. All rows for ID where `rich==1` should be included in the development file, and filled up to 75% of data with all rows associated with an ID. To clarify, the 75%-25% split should by ID, not by observations.